# Where are skype profile data saved (age, location etc.)

Tags: skype

I know part of it is probably cloud based but it probably is saved on disk too. Where can I find this? Thanks

Comment: Fairly certain it's all on Skype's servers

Comment: fairly safe assumption, considering what happens if you sign in from a fresh machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out by myself. What you need to do is type "`%appdata%\skype in run`" like vembutech said, this part can be easily found tough and I had figured it out before. What you need to do next is download `SQLite` database browser open `main.db`, select browse tab and "`accounts`" table. Then you just need to find columns you are looking for ex. `birthday`.

Answer (score 0):

open  `%appdata%\skype in run` and you can find your file name folder and inside that folder you will find "config.xml" file where you can find your profile information like your profile picture. Regarding the age and other info's I suspect that they might save it in database file available in the location.